# How to center a modal window inside Facebook App?

Tags: jquery, facebook-apps

I'm developing a Facebook App using their iframe method.  How do I find my position in the iframe to center a modal window?

Calling $(window.height()) returns the iframe page height and not the parent page.  Using scrollTop() doesn't work because we're not on the same domain.  Any help would be appreciated.

These guys are able to do it somehow, but I can't figure it out...
http://apps.facebook.com/mylistfb/?r=true

Comment: If you want to scroll your iframe app to a certain position, you can use `FB.Canvas.scrollTo` – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  But I'm not looking to scroll my iframe.  I just want to add a modal window centered to where I'm at in the iframe.  For instance, if you go to the link above, you can scroll halfway down that page, click on an image, and a modal window pops up centered.

Answer (score 4):

Found it, sorry newbie to FB apps.  Missed it in the FB docs.

```
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
    function(info) {
        alert(info.scrollTop);
    }
);
```

(*The number of pixels between the top edge of your iframe and the top edge of your iframe's viewport)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/